# Existence of complete sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid r.v.'s, each with pdf $f_{\theta}(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}I\{\theta<x<2\theta\}$. I find the minimal sufficient statistics $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$. I am trying to prove it is complete. Can someone give me hint? Also are there any complete sufficient statistics in this model?

Comment: Consider that it must be that $\theta < X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)} < 2\theta$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate : That is clearly true, and it means that $(X_{(n)}/2,\  X_{(1)})$ is a $100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$, but I'm afraid I don't see where you're going with this. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate. Can you tell me more?

Comment: @DilipSarwate. Are you suggesting using $g(T)=X_{(1)}-X_{(n)}/2$?

Comment: IT IS NOT COMPLETE.

Comment: @user81235 : The statistic $g(T)$ that you asked about is always positive, so it cannot be an unbiased estimator of $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I find $E(X_{(1)})=2\theta-\frac{n\theta}{n+1}$, and $E(X_{(n)})=\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}\theta$. I was trying to derive a linear combination of them and make them as 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$\operatorname{E} (X_{(1)}) = \theta + \dfrac \theta {n+1} = \dfrac{n+2}{n+1} \theta$$ and $$\operatorname{E}(X_{(n)}) = 2\theta - \dfrac{\theta}{n+1} = \dfrac {2n+1} {n+1} \theta,$$ so
$$
\operatorname{E} \left( \frac{n+1}{n+2} X_{(1)} - \frac{n+1}{2n+1} X_{(n)} \right) = 0
$$
regardless of the value of $\theta>0$.

Therefore, the statistic $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is **not** complete.

Comment: You're really fast!

Comment: I am not quite sure about this statement: minimal sufficient statistic is not complete implies any sufficient statistic is not complete.

Comment: If you know the value of a sufficient statistic $T$, then you can compute the value of the minimal sufficient statistic, and from that you can compute a function that is an unbiased estimator of $0$.  Thus some function of $T$ is an unbiased estimator or $0$, so $T$ is not complete. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5):

Find $E(X_{(1)})$ and $E(X_{(n)})$. Play with them to make it $0$ i.e. find $a,b$ such that $E[aX_{(1)}+bX_{(n)}]=0$. Call $g(T)=aX_{(1)}+bX_{(n)}$. Then we have $E[g(T)]=0$ but does that mean $g(T)=0$ a.e.? No right?